# Edit form data load and pass - ngModel and formControl

Tags: angular

i need to verify im in the right way , here is my code for the data edit and save component please review and give me a feedback :)

in my view

```
<div [formGroup]="policyForm">
    <div formGroupName="PolicyDetail" class="col-md-4">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">
                    Post Code
                </label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="policyDetail.postcode" formControlName="PostCode" placeholder="Post Code" />
            </div>
 </div>
```

my ts file

```
  this.policyService.getPolicyDetails().subscribe(
            (data) => {

                this.policyDetail = data.policyDetail;
 },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Failure Policy Details');

            });


 this.policyForm = new FormGroup({

 PolicyDetail: new FormGroup({
                PostCode: new FormControl(),
 }),
  });
```

i use the [ngModel]  to visible data in my input controller and use FormGroup  to collect data and validate etc ...

is it correct to use ngModel and formControl  both ? or is there are way to set data to controller without ngModel ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a reactive form, make use of the formcontrols, you can set the value with them. Since you have incoming data from api, I would also suggest you use `patchValue`, that sets the values *after* data has been retrieved to not get an error thrown, since this is an async operation. So set the default values as empty.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, .....) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.getPolicyDetails();

  this.policyForm = this.fb.group({
    PostCode: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}

getPolicyDetails() {
  this.policyService.getPolicyDetails().subscribe(data => {
     this.policyDetail = data.policyDetail;
     // Now we have the values, let's use patchValue!
     this.setValues();
  });
}

setValues() {
  this.policyForm
    .patchValue({
       PostCode: this.policyDetail.postcode
  })
}
```

So now you can skip `ngModel` from your form altogether:

```
<div [formGroup]="policyForm">
   <input type="text" formControlName="PostCode" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: hi how can i use pipes with form contoller ? as a convert this code to form controller   
[ngModel]="policyModel?.amendmentDate | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'"

Answer (score 2):

No , you should use either `ngModel` or `FormControl` it will always emerge an error if you'll use them both, if you want to use `ngModel` inside a `Reactive Form` you should add `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` to the tag attributes. check [this](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-custom-form-controls-with-reactive-forms-and-ngmodel) and [this](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive#ngmodule-and-reactive-forms) for more informations.